Specify output directory
Please have a look at the code at the end of the post. If I save it into test.qmd when I use
quarto render test.qmd

then the docx file is created in the local working directory where the script is located and not in the ../output directory.
What am I doing wrong?
I run debian stable and I use the latest quarto.
---
title: "Custom Output Example"
format:
  docx:
    output-file: "output_file.docx"
output-dir: "../output"
---


See this GitHub reply   .  In the terminal, you need to specifify  output-dir ../output  ;  such as quarto render test.qmd --output-dir ../output .  In the .qmd, output-dir: "../output" seems ignored

I see. Even if it is not what I hoped for, thanks and I will mark this as the correct answer. I hope to see this feature implemented in the future.

I understand your point and agree with you. For your information, as alternative, you can use R function quarto::quarto_render() . A output_file cans be specified as argument, but you can specifiy a directory.  file.copy()  is handy in a second step. I had the idea to make a user-function, inspired by this nice blog by Meghan Hall: https://meghan.rbind.io/blog/2022-09-25-tips-for-custom-parameterized-pdfs-in-quarto/ .
Let me know if you think it should be in my answer.
